# Passing URL parameters to a TFS Report (2010)

Tags: url, parameters, tfs, report, analysis

I have a very simple report constructed using Report Builder 2.0 talking to analysis services for TFS 2010. The report shows the number of active bugs logged against a particular Team Project, sorted by priority.

I have several team projects, and I don't want to duplicate the same report for each one. Instead, I would like to pass in the team project as a parameter in the URL. A search of the web shows good guidance from John Socha-Leialoha on how to do this (finding the MDX parameter and constructing the query).

I have set a default on the report to point to a particular team project and the report presents the expected information, when I add a parameter to the URL the report fails to run, and displays the following message: `'Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: main'`

The following URL displays the report correctly with the default team project:

```
/sites/tfsserver/_layouts/TfsRedirect.aspx?tf:Type=Report&tf:ReportName=Bug+Information/ActiveBugsByPriorityBarChart
```

I've also tried appending the parameter, as follows:

```
/sites/tfsserver/_layouts/TfsRedirect.aspx?tf:Type=Report&tf:ReportName=Bug+Information/ActiveBugsByPriorityBarChart&tf:Parameters=TeamProjectTeamProjectHierarchy=[Team Project].[Team Project Hierarchy].&[{E207FAFF-CA70-41A2-8A62-B881C9C9F8F1}]
```

This, also, generates the message: `'Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: main'`

This led me to the realization that I needed to escape the `&` symbol, as follows:

```
/sites/tfsserver/_layouts/TfsRedirect.aspx?tf:Type=Report&tf:ReportName=Bug+Information/ActiveBugsByPriorityBarChart&tf:Parameters=TeamProjectTeamProjectHierarchy=[Team Project].[Team Project Hierarchy].&26[{E207FAFF-CA70-41A2-8A62-B881C9C9F8F1}]
```

However, the report still fails to run, and displays the same error message.

Since it is not referenced in Socha's example, I have also tried running the report while omitting the `&tf:` parameters tag, as follows:

```
/sites/tfsserver/_layouts/TfsRedirect.aspx?tf:Type=Report&tf:ReportName=Bug+Information/ActiveBugsByPriorityBarChart&TeamProjectTeamProjectHierarchy=[Team Project].[Team Project Hierarchy].&26[{E207FAFF-CA70-41A2-8A62-B881C9C9F8F1}]
```

This doesn't seem to work either. At this point, I'm happy for any advice/guidance  I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this blog post helps you: http://ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/06/02/Add-SSRS-report-as-dashboard-to-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: Rather than use tfsredirect, referencing the report directly and appending the parameter returned the expected results.  http://ReportServer?%2fTfsReportsBug+Information%2fActiveBugsByPriorityBarChart&rc%3aToolbar=false&TeamProjectTeamProjectHierarchy=[Team Project].[Team Project Hierarchy].%26[{EDDA8EDA-B824-4DBA-A2B9-E5DF674A1FCF}]
.  Do you know why only the & requires escaping and not characters such as {{= Many thanks for your help